# `source .bashrc` displaying `: command not found`

Tags: bash, ubuntu

The following command is giving
I see this every time I open up a new terminal window on my machine:

```
user:~$ source .bashrc
: command not found
user:~$ source ~/.bashrc
: command not found
```

I've tried emptying the entire contents of my `.bashrc` file too but that doesn't seem to remove the error, and I'm not sure at this point what could be going on.

Has anyone run into a similar issue like this before?

Thanks!

Comment: Your file has dos line endings. Remove them.

Comment: @KamilCuk i tried `fromdos .bashrc` to remove them but am still getting the error. maybe I'm doing it wrong?

Comment: Does fromdos rewrite the file? `dos2unix .bashrc` or `sed -i 's/\r$//' .bashrc`

Comment: @glennjackman I don't think it does. I tried `dos2unix .bashrc` and it worked!!! thanks so much!